# How do I manage my finances using Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to track my spendings in Emacs (and, perhaps, Org-Mode).
Are there any tools/techniques available for this purpose?

Actually, I only need a couple of simple features:

- Easy tracking of one-time and recurring earnings and spendings;
- Weekly/monthly reports (as with the Org-Mode's time tracker).

Comment: how do you manage it...badly :-) ...anyway aren't there better free programs to do this?

Comment: Sure there are (GnuCash and whatnot), but at least for time tracking I've never seen anything better than the Org-Mode's clock. I hope that there might be some similar solution for personal finance management in the Emacs environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find [hledger](http://hledger.org/) quite nice. It operates on text files in a fairly readable format. I think you could get org-capture to append new transactions to a file even though it's not an org-mode file, but I haven't tried it myself, as I mostly do CSV imports.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is exactly what I need - a simple CLI interface &  working on plain text files. Even better that it's written in Haskell. ;)

Comment: There is also an org-mode tutorial using `ledger` cli, at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-ledger.html, but I am leaning towards `hledger` as well at the moment. The web-ui/plain-text pair is just too enticing.